# Error: 'Exception thrown while unbinding java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: ll@3b848368' in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json

I have been frustrated by again and again trying to resolve the issue I am getting in Android Studio. I know there are a lot of question like this on internet but none of them work with me. I am trying to test the app in LDPlayer. I actually have an activity opening another activity:

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, prac_ques.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This is all my code. The activity that opens('activity A') get the data from another class(class B)

> activity A code

```
public static String selected_ans = "";

RadioButton radioButton;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
public static RadioButton ch1;
public static RadioButton ch2;
public static RadioButton ch3;
public static RadioButton ch4;
public static TextView textView;
public static Button click;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = findViewById(selectedId);
    ch1 = findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    ch2 = findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    ch3 = findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    ch4 = findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    selected_ans = selected_ans + radioButton.getText().toString();
    class_a process = new class_a();
    process.execute();
    textView = findViewById(R.id.questions);
    click = findViewById(R.id.button);
}
```

> Here is class a code

```
public class class_a extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void> {
int over;
int ans;
String raw_dat = "";
String question = "";
String question2 = "";
String ch1 = "";
String ch2 = "";
String ch3 = "";
String ch4 = "";
String anss = "";
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("json_url");
        HttpURLConnection htc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = htc.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String raw = "";
        while (raw != null){
            raw = br.readLine();
            raw_dat = raw_dat+raw;
        }
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(raw_dat);
        for (int i = 0; i == 0; i++) {
            JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            question = "" + jo.get("question");
            ch1 = "" + jo.get("cha");
            ch2 = "" + jo.get("chb");
            ch3 = "" + jo.get("chc");
            ch4 = "" + jo.get("chd");
            anss = "" + jo.get("ans");
        }
        for (int i = 1; i == 1; i++){
            JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            question2 = "" +jo.get("question");
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    activity_a.ch1.setText(ch1);
    activity_a.ch2.setText(ch2);
    activity_a.ch3.setText(ch3);
    activity_a.ch4.setText(ch4);
    activity_a.textView.setText(question);
    activity_a.click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            over++;
            if (activity_a.selected_ans.equals(anss)){
                ans++;
            }

            activity_a.textView.setText(question2);
            activity_a.click.setOnClickListener(null);
            activity_a.click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    over++;
                    activity_a.textView.setText("over !!");
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

}
I am in a big trouble please help me.... Thank you in advance.